# How can I Identify users on an internal site without requiring credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-5

Currently I am using windows authentication but several of the non technical users seem to have trouble entering their credentials when the browser requests them.  The web app needs to be able to identify the users to keep track of their input throughout the site.  I was initially thinking cookie but I would need to be able to tell which users entered what and the possibility of them clearing their cookies could cause issues.  windows Authentication would be great if I could just get around requiring the users to enter their credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a properly configured network, internet explorer users should not have to enter their credintials.  Furthermore, I think all the other browsers have settings to do automatic NTLM authentication (Chrome and Firefox definitely do).

What do you mean "have troup entering their credientials"?   How do they log in to their computer?

Comment: One common issue is that the FQDN is considered to be in the internet zone and not the intranet

Comment: @Mark Sowul, Yes, that can be an issue.  However, a properly configured network and computers (I'm assuming IT sets up everyones machines) will resolve without a fully qualified name.

Comment: Right that is the issue I am dealing with now.  We use a FQDN for the internal site and would like to keep it that way if possible.  This is a very low priority project so any configuration changes to the browser like adding the site to the intranet zone will get shut down.

Comment: I find many if not most places use the same internal and external domain names and that ruins lots of things.  (Presumably if simple a browser GPO is off the table, so is renaming the domain)